# Sort by column 1 and tuple(column2,column3) then expand again

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and this seems to be a bit tricky for me:

I have 3 columns:

```
column1 : id
column2 : size
column3 : rank
```

I now want to re-align the id column and keeping size,rank in order together (size,rank)

so it would look like:

```
id:1 (size,rank):4,5
id:2 (size,rank):5,8
```

So the id column has to be reorded from 1 to 1000 and not messing up the (size,rank) tupel

I tried to do:

```
combined = zip(size,rank)

id, combined = zip(*sorted(zip(id, combined)))
```

Is this correct? And if yes, how can I seperate the tupel to 2 arrays size and rank again.

I heard about `zip(*combined)`?

unziped = zip(*combined)

then `size equals unziped[0] and rank equals unziped[1]` ?

Thank you for help!

ADDED from `Numpy genfromtxt function`

```
 size= [x[2] for x in mydata]
 rank= [x[1] for x in mydata]
```

Comment: `3` columns in what? A nested `list`?

Comment: No 3 seperate columns

Comment: What do you mean by a "column"?

Comment: I used genfromtxt in numpy and it generates and array I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is you are using the `id` column as both an identifier and as the value by which the data is ordered. This is wrong. Leave the id column alone; and then sort the data by only size; once you have it sorted use `enumerate` to list the "order".

Here is an example, which sorts the data by the second column (size), then prints the data along with their "rank" or "order":

```
>>> data = ((1, 4, 5), (3, 6, 7), (4, 3, 3), (19, 32, 0))
>>> data_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> for k,v in enumerate(data_sorted):
...   print('{}: {}'.format(k+1, v))
...
1: (4, 3, 3)
2: (1, 4, 5)
3: (3, 6, 7)
4: (19, 32, 0)
```

Comment: The ids are unsorted and should be aligned 1...1000 and sorted by ids. Since rank and size are already referencing the correct id.

Comment: You cannot have one value `id` mean two things. It either means the id, or the "sort order". Since as you say size and rank are already linked with their correct ids - best not to shuffle the ids around.